# Pre-filter shiny data table?

Tags: r, shiny

I am using R with Rstudio and Shiny to display the data from a `data.table` using `renderDataTable`. How do I set up my data.table so that when it loads some of the columns are prefiltered?

```
library(data.table)
output$od_hsmm.summaries = renderDataTable({
summary.dt = hsmm.load_summary_r()
summary.dt = summary.dt[,.SD, .SDcols = c('spec.runid', 'spec.wrp', 'spec.log', 'nStates', 'fit.ll', 'fit.ll.imp', 'fit.bic')]
setnames(summary.dt, 
         c('spec.runid', 'spec.wrp', 'spec.log', 'nStates', 'fit.ll', 'fit.ll.imp', 'fit.bic'),
         c('runid', 'repeat.obs', 'log.obs', 'nStates', 'loglik', 'll.improves', 'bic'))
return(summary.dt)
})
```

I'd like my DataTable to start up in my shiny app only displaying runid == 1, repeat.obs == 0

To clarify, I'd like to use Shiny's renderDataTable options to do this  - I dont want to subset my data.table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does replacing `return(summary.dt)` by `subset(summary.dt,runid==1 & repeat.obs==0)` give what you want?

Comment: @Stibu No - that doesn't use shiny's built in options - if I want the user to be able to view the entire table later I'd have to unsubset.